# Regex for Number (or) Number and Comma (or) Number Comma and Space (or) Number Comma Space Number

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex learning and I am trying to achieve the below. I will be really thankful to anyone who can help me in my learning

What I'm trying to achieve
Number (or) Number and Comma (or) Number Comma and Space (or) Number Comma Space Number

**My Regex: (^\d$)|(^\d,+$)|(^\d\s+$)|(^\d,\s)+$|(^\d,+\d)$**

Complete Test Data URL : https://regexr.com/5eogj

***Pass Data***

- 11
- 11,11
- 1, 111,11
- 111,,,
- 11, [whitespace]
- 1 , 1

***Fail/Invalid Data***

- ABC
- Any Special Characters other than comma and space
- 111 1111

Comment: Looks like you want `^\d+(?:,(?:\s+\d*)?)?$`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Wiktor. But, it is not working as expected for the test data.
https://regexr.com/5eogj

Comment: Maybe `/^\s*\d+(?:\s*,+\s*\d*)*\s*$/gm`? Note you do not enable `m` in your regexr test set and did not set correct expected results for failing tests. See https://regexr.com/5eogp

Comment: I'd lose the beginning/end markers. If you use matches, they are assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\s*\d+(?:\s*,+\s*\d*)*\s*$
```

See the [regex tests at regexr](https://regexr.com/5eogp).

When you use it in Java to validate your input strings, use

```
str.matches("\\s*\\d+(?:\\s*,+\\s*\\d*)*\\s*")
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*,+\s*\d*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `,+` - one or more commas
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is perfect!!!
Thank you so much for explaining it as well. Makes learning easy and fun :)